# iPhone type Background Control for WPF

Tags: c#, iphone, .net, wpf

I want to create an app that is somewhat of an iPhone emulator (and by emulator I mean user control that looks like a picture of an iPhone but it's still just all .NET under the hood).

I just want to use it to demonstrate/prototype some ideas and see how it would look on the phone and could demonstrate it's functionality to others.  Why WPF?  Because I'm a .NET developer and I don't want to spend much time on learning something I may never use.

Does anyone know if a control like this exists?  Or a pre-made style?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want an iphone picture and then the ability to put arbitrary controls inside of it, do something like this inside your XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="iphone.png" />
    </Grid.Background>
    <Frame Name="sourceFrame" Source="springboard.xaml" Margin="left,top,right,bottom" />
</Grid>
```

iPhone.png needs to be a picture of the iphone. You can find these readily available on the internet. Open the image in a picture editor and find the distance to the left side of the actual screen and put that in the margin for left. Do the same for top, right, and bottom. Then just create springboard.xaml, and you're set.

Comment: Wow.  That was much easier than expected.  :)  Thanks!